# Installation error for Intel Fortran Compiler on Windows-PC: "Failed to load package"

Tags: windows, intel-oneapi

As stated in the header, I'm trying to install the Intel Fortran Compiler on my Windows-PC but always get the following error:
[image]

The error occurs not only for the installation of Fortran compiler but as well for the installation of other Intel applications, like the C++ compiler.

I tried the installation with both offline and online versions as well as with and without pre-installed MS Visual Studio, but the error continues to occur.

If I try to open the "log"-file, I get an empty message-window:
[image]

I use a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700 prozessor.

Thanks in advance for any bit of information and help.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing on a different Windows-account I figured out the solution. My normal username contains a "ö" which probaply caused the error.